# How to divide unique data from an sql server to two different computers

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I am looking to use multiple computers to run a python script. I'd like to feed unique data from mysql to each computer running the script. I have a semi-working solution but the problem is when 2 scripts run it at the same, before either can update the status column to "processing" it will choose the same data.

I've tried:

```py
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE status IS NULL FOR UPDATE"
```

but that just seemed to lock my second connection out of the database completely without allowing it to fetch the data below it for processing.

I have also tried the code below, which works, but only if 2 scripts don't try to access the db at the same time.

```py
vids = []
ids = []
c.execute('SELECT video_id,url FROM videos WHERE status IS NULL LIMIT 100;')
data = c.fetchall()
for row in data:
    vids.append((row[1],row[0]))
    ids.append(row[0])

c.executemany('UPDATE videos SET status="processing" WHERE video_id=%s;', ids)
db.commit()
```

I'd like for each computer to grab unique sets of data for processing. Script 1 grabs 1-100, script 2 grabs 101-200, script 3 grabs 201-300, etc.

Thanks for the help! Have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my suggestion

you can use mysql [lock tables](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-table-locking/), but you need to update your query to:

```
c.execute('lock tables videos; UPDATE videos SET status="processing" WHERE video_id in (select t1.video_id from (select video_id, row_number() over (order by video_id) as rn from videos where coalesce(status, '') = '') as t1 where rn <= 100); unlock tables;')
```

this solution is only applicable for `mysql versionn 8.0` up.

you don't need the for loop on this.

Comment: Hello, I have tried using this but I am receiving the error message: ```ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'```. I also had to remove the "lock tables videos;" and "unlock tables" as it was giving me a syntax error. I guess I'll have to run those as 3 separate executes? Does this give me the data I'm looking for? I need the URL and the video_id, this seems like it just updates without returning any data.

Comment: updated, forgot the closing parentheses, please try again

Comment: ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: @Canna, what's the mysql version you are using?